# How to test a catch clause if I can't reproduce the error during the test?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs, supertest

I'm using Jest ans Supertest in my Server Side Application. I was hoping to increase the coverage of my test by obviously testing every uncovered line, until I got blocked by this:

```
Activity.find()
    .then((data) => {
        res.json(data);
    }).catch(e => res.status(400).send(e));
```

How can I test the catch clause if I can't reproduce that kind of error in my tests (or at least I don't know how)?

Answer (score 0):

In unit-test your should test only your code and should not rely on 3rd party libraries. Of course, this advice should be applied reasonably (e.g. we must depend on the compiler and out-of-box libraries of the platform we are using).

Up to now it seemed reasonable not to stub `json` as it's a quite established library you can rely on. But as soon as you want test such behavior as thrown exceptions there is no other way than create a stub, inject it somehow into your code, and in test setup make it throw an exception when calling `json`.

As a side effect, this will decouple your code from a particular implementation of `json` and make your code more flexible. Of course decoupling from JSON implementations seems a bit over the top, but nevertheless shows how test-driven design works in this case (even though the code was first).

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a catch case by stubbing the method. First you should stub find method of Activity and then make it throw and error.
If you were using sinon;

```
sinon.stub(Activity, "find").rejects(new Error("Simulated Error!)
```

Probably for jest it is like;

```
jest.spyOn(Activity, "find").mockRejectedValue(new Error("Simulated Error!)
```

After that with supertest you can test your endpoint like;

```
const res = await request(app).get('/your-route')
expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(500)
expect(res.body).toEqual(new Error("Simulated Error!"))
expect(res.body.message).toEqual("Simulated Error!")
```

With this way you can test catch cases by simulating it and increase your coverage.